# Importing a file using “import(`./player/${file}`)” doesn’t result in the expected value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, commonjs, dynamic-import

I have this piece of code which works on CommonJS but I want to switch my project over to ES6 but I get the error that `.bind` isn’t a function, so I wonder if there is anyone who knows how I would switch this over.

```js
for (const file of player) {
  const event = import(`./player/${file}`);

  Storage.player.on(file.split(".")[0], event.bind(null, client));
}
```

Comment: `event` is definitely a function?

Comment: `bind` is `bind`. What’s the *complete* error?

Comment: The complete error is "TypeError: event.bind is not a function"

Comment: event.bind() worked before i tried to convert it to es6 danromoon

Comment: I would guess it's because ES6 doesn't have the dynamic imports? If so, then you would need to replace the import with `import * as event from `./player/${file}`;`

Comment: @2pichar Technically correct, but dynamic import does exist since ECMAScript 2020, and it seems to be working in OP’s environment since this would result in a SyntaxError otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You’re using a dynamic import.
Take a look at the [documentation on MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports):

> To dynamically import a module, the `import` keyword may be called as a function. When used this way, it returns a promise.

So you have a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), not a [`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function).
As always, you can simply use `console.log(event);` or any other [debugging technique](https://ali-dev.medium.com/how-to-easily-debug-in-javascript-5bac70f94f1a) to inspect what `event` actually is.

If you’re inside an [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) or [*top-level* in an ES6 module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#top_level_await), you can simply try using the [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) keyword in front of `import`.
However, you can always use [`.then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) to receive the imported value.
Make sure to also handle import errors, e.g. using [`.catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch).

See [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/4642212).

As you’re importing things in a loop, consider using asynchronous iteration techniques like [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).
`player` is an iterable; if it’s also an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) you can use the [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method and bind all listeners using a dynamic import within the callback.
You can definitely use the second argument of [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), if that doesn’t work.

So, here’s my suggestion of how to rewrite this code, although with more context, there may be better ways to deal with the asynchronicity:

```js
player.forEach(async (file) => Storage.player.on(
  file.split(".")[0],
  (await import(`./player/${file}`)).bind(null, client)
));
```

Besides error handling, all you have left to do is to assert that all imported files actually resolve to a Function, otherwise you still won’t have a `.bind` method.